# What is the role of square bracket in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I don't understand the square bracket role

```
System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
```

Can anyone tell me what is the role of square bracket in above statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [[] Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3hd7ste.aspx):

> Square brackets (**`[]`**) are used for arrays, indexers, and attributes.
>   They can also be used with pointers.

Answer (score 4):

This syntax is specific to C#, not to .NET, and indicates the declaration of an array.

Answer (score 3):

This says that the variable `ServicesToRun` is an array of `ServiceBase` instances. See here for more informations about arrays:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx